# Do Kofax Capture Mobile SDK have a trial version for iOS?

Tags: ios, mobile, sdk, capture, kofax

I wanted to work on the Kofax Capture Mobile SDK for iOS , but have not bought the product. Mean while i want to start working on it , Do they have a trial version that i can work on till i buy their product? Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You could sign-up [here](http://www.atalasoft.com/Downloads) and get the 30-day trial. You would get a licence key from which you could evaluate.